# Generate an audio file which makes rhythmic buzzer sounds

Tags: sound

I will perform an experiment which consists of deadlift trials during 5 minutes. 
To control the rhythm of this fatiguing exercise, I would like to generate a sound file which gives a buzzer noise every 7.5 seconds.

In *Mathematica*'s documentation,

```
Play[Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

can generate a 1-second buzzer noise. But how do I generate a 6.5-second silence and merge the noise-silence together, and repeat them as much as we want?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?  Generating a buzz (did you look at `Play`)?  Stitching it together with a stretch of silence?  Proceed step by step and ask specific questions.

Comment: Thank you, I can now generate a buzzer. This question gets more specific now.

Comment: With `AudioJoin`.

Comment: Here's something to think about: what do you think would you get if you multiplied your sinusoid with a square wave with appropriate amplitude and period?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:

Make a 1 second beep with harmonics:

```
Play[Sum[1/k Sin[k 400 2 Pi t], {k, 1, 4}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Modulate it with another sine wave if you want to make it sound rougher:

```
beep = Play[Sum[1/k Sin[k 400 2 Pi t] (0.75 + 0.25 Sin[60 2 Pi t]), {k, 1, 4}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Add 6.5 seconds of silence for a total of 7.5 seconds

```
au = AudioJoin[{beep, AudioGenerator["Silence", 6.5]}]
```

Repeat this 40 times for 5 minutes of data.

```
result = AudioJoin@ConstantArray[au, 40]

Export["result.wav", result]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What a pity that my MMA is a student version (available as long as I am a student), The version of 10.4.1 can not be updated to have AudioGenerator and AudioJoin functions.

Comment: @ToughKid Create the data directly then, with `Table`, and use `ListPlay` (or `SampledSoundList`)

Comment: Thanks very much, SampledSoundList do the job. I've done it this way.  Export["Beep.mp3", Sound[SampledSoundList[
   Flatten[ConstantArray[
     Join[Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] 500 t], {t, 0, 1, 1./2000}], 
      ConstantArray[0, 13000]],
     100]],
   2000]]]

Answer (score 2):

First make a $440 \text{ Hz}$ wave ($1 \text{ s}$):

```
a = Audio @ Play[Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 1}];
```

Add $6.5 \text{ s}$ silence:

```
b = AudioPad[a, 6.5]
```

Join them. Repeat `b` for $5\times 60/7.5=40$ times.

```
au = AudioJoin[Table[b, Round[5*60/7.5]]];
AudioPlot[au, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Szabolcs 's answer and idea of SampledSoundList, I've done it in this way. I post it out for those who have not the lastest version of MMA.

```
Export["C:\\Users\\Wei\\Downloads\\Beep2.mp3",
 Sound[
  SampledSoundList[
   Flatten[
    ConstantArray[
     Join[
      Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] 500 t], {t, 0, 1, 1./2000}],
      ConstantArray[0, 13000]
      ],
     200]
    ],
   2000
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of the idea I gave in the comments. `Piecewise[]` is quite convenient to use here when using `Play[]`:

```
With[{n = 6},
     Play[Piecewise[{{Sin[440 2 Pi t], 0 <= Mod[t, 15/2] <= 1}}, 0],
          {t, 0, 15 n/2}, SampleRate -> 8192]]
```

For the `Audio[]` version:

```
With[{n = 6},
     ts = TimeSeries[Transpose[{FoldList[Plus, 0, PadRight[{}, 2 n, {1, 13/2}]], 
                                PadRight[{}, 2 n + 1, {440, 0}]}]];
     AudioGenerator[{"Sin", ts}]]
```